# Automatically updating database with multiple DbContexts

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first, asp.net-identity, dbcontext

I'm using EF6 in ASP.NET 5 project. Where I'm using ASP.NET Identity as the authentication mechanism. As anyone would do, I have modeled my domain objects in a separate dll project and for data access logic I have a separate project. This data project contains EF migrations, DbContext for domain models, repositories and Unit of work.

And I have a service layer which is contacted by ASP.NET controllers and this service layer will communicate with data layer and do required operations.

In the main ASP.NET web project I have the default DbContext which is related to Identity and it's migrations.

Having two DbContexts somehow prevents me from updating database automatically. If I had only one DbContext after I create migrations for model changes, it will automatically run on the first time I try to access the website. This doesn't happen anymore, always I have to run the "update-database" command manually.

One solution I have right now is to add a reference to "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework" in my data project and use Identity context contain my domain tables. But adding an ASP.NET reference in my data project is something I don't want to do unless I have no other options. Because data layer is not even communicating directly with web layer.

Even though [this](http://pluralsight.com/training/Player?author=scott-allen&name=aspdotnet-mvc5-fundamentals-m6-ef6&mode=live&clip=2&course=aspdotnet-mvc5-fundamentals) video by Scott Allen discuss about this issue, a solution is not proposed.

Comment: Hi Geethanga, I have same projects with you, and I got almost same issue here: I can update two databases if I switch between the 2 projects in the package management console. But if I publish the project to azure, only dll project's migration got executed, the migration in web project(which conatins identityContext) doesn't have option to run migration.     Can you tells more about how you using DBMigrator to update your database? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can kick in migrations explicitly by using [database initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696323(v=vs.113).aspx) and using [`MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh829293(v=vs.113).aspx). This initializer allows you explicitly state the context and configuration you want to use. Something like:

```
SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyContext, Configuration>());
```

You can also call all the logic manually, effectively doing the same as `Update-Database` cmdlet, when you want during app start. Look at [`DbMigrator` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigrator(v=vs.113).aspx).

Comment: I opted to handle the situation using DbMigrator with a call from Startup

Answer (score 1):

You can run migration inside each DbContext constructor separately.

```
public class DataContext: DbContext 
{
    static DaraContext() 
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<DataContext, Configuration>());
    }
}


public class ApplicationDbContext : IndetityDbContext 
{
    static ApplicationDbContext() 
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ApplicationDbContext, Configuration>());
    }
}
```

Comment: I opted to handle the situation using DbMigrator with a call from Startup. I'm not using Initializers.